# Added some word in the middle of existing text using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Here my code for example.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Do you really want to delete  files ?</p>
</div>
```

I would like to add a word `Insert_your_file_here` between word `delete` and word `files` and a word `right now` at the end of the text. I can handle the `right now` sentences, but not with `Document1` word.

What i expect the result is just like this.

```
<div class="modal-body">
      <p>Do you really want to delete Document1 file right now ?</p>
</div>
```

WHat i have tried is use `append` but i dont know how to specific location of the word that would be added

```
$('.modal-body p').append('Document1');
$('.modal-body p').append('right now');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var text = $('.modal-body p').text();
  text = text.substr(0,28)+' Document1 , Document2 '+text.substr(29 ,-1)+' right now?'
  $('.modal-body p').text(text)
```

**Let me explain:**

substr() method is used to extract string and make sub-string of big string . (0,28 ) is the position of string to be extracted starting from 0 till 28 position and (29,-1) means start from 29 and end at -1 from backward .Negative positioning is to be counted from backwards .

If your document is in list of array :

```
var text = $('.modal-body p').text();
  var document = ['Document1','Document2'].join(' , ');
  text = text.substr(0,28)+' '+ document +text.substr(29 ,-1)+' right now?'
     $('.modal-body p').text(text)
```

Comment: could you explain to me what is 29, -1 mean ?

Comment: or 0,28 substr mean ?

Comment: To position the string from end -ve can be put , from backward it will be like 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 . Imagine if  string is circular

Comment: 0,28 - Start from 0 index till 28th position

Comment: ohhh make sense

Comment: could you added tht to your answer ?

Comment: 29,-1 means - start from 29 position till -1 from backwards

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending, you can set the entire text in jQuery:

```
var documentName = "Document1";
$('.modal-body p').text("Do you really want to delete " + documentName + " right now?");
```

Then you can change the `documentName` variable to whatever you want.